# Cakephp Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: cakephp, domdocument

I tried to implement rss feed following this simple explanation from cake book http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/rss.html
I got this error 
   "Class 'DOMDocument' not found in lib/Cake/Utility/Xml.php on line 99"

Any clue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install php-xml package that provides the needed files to use the DOMDocument class

Comment: php-xml package has already installed and unfortunately it doesn't fix problem... Any other solution?

Comment: have you restarted the webserver since you installed that?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same trouble, **with** installed package. I tried to load it with `new DOMDocument();` but I had to use `$dom = new \DOMDocument();`

Hope this helps people using CakePHP 3.x